# The mass change of electron after absorbing photon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

If a photon is absorbed by an electron, will the rest mass of the electron increase? Or will the relativistic mass of the electron increase?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at.  First, individual electrons don't absorb photons.  Systems of charged particles (i.e., more than one charged  particles) do.  Second, the rest mass of an elementary particle does not change.

Comment: Such as photo electrical effect

Comment: In the photoelectric effect, the photon is absorbed by the metal, and the electron is accelerated.  Its rest mass does not change.

Comment: @garyp I agree with you totally. But I am curious about a question. If the electron has been excited by the photon, now we use a negative electric field around the atom to limit the movement of the electron, what will happen next?

Comment: nice question, rest mass will not increase because it in motion only relativistic mass of the electron increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are good answers, but I want to introduce the representation of Feynman diagrams, because that is what is being used when studying the behavior of elementary particles, and both the photon and the electron are elementary particles. These diagrams are used to calculate the probability of interaction , a strict mathematical operation implied by it.

[image: compt]

The squiggly line represents the four momentum of a photon , and the dark the four momentum of the electron. The interaction happens at the points called vertices. What happens is that for a tiny interval of the variable the photon is absorbed completely in a summed four vector in the internal dark line , and the electron and photon reappear with the scattered momenta/energies at a second vertex. Between the two vertices An integral is applied over the variables and the boundary conditions of the problem.

The incoming and outgoing electron have the invariant mass given by the four vector they are carrying. Only energy and momentum change with the absorption of part of the energy of the incoming photon.

It has to be stressed that for a free electron there will always be a scattered off photon, even of very low energy, because of momentum conservation at the center of mass, there cannot be two particles coming in and one going out.

> If a photon is absorbed by an electron, will the rest mass of the electron increase?

The answer is no, it is not called an *invariant mass* in vain.

> Or will the relativistic mass of the electron increase?

Yes, the relativistic mass will increase. The concept is not really useful at the particle level. It is useful where newtonian mechanics is assumed, and newtonian forces are estimated, as with starships and the velocity of light, but it is confusing terminology at the particle level.

The case of electrons bound in an atom is covered by other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Relativistic mass is an archaic concept, and I believe, it is not used by professional physicists any longer. No. The rest mass won't increase only its momentum will change and it will scatter.

Comment: Can you give me more explanations on the electron scattering?

Comment: If the photon is absorbed by an electron at rest, then the electron scatters off with the same momentum as that of the photon, to conserve momentum.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the sort of process you thinking about is [Compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering) where a photon hits a free electron and transfers energy to it. The scattered electron ends up with an increased energy, but this does not produce an increased mass.

The relativistic expression for the total energy of a particle is:

$$ E^2 = p^2 c^2 + m^2c^4 $$

where the $m$ in this equation is the rest mass, which is a constant. The increased energy of the electron after the photon has hit it comes from an increase in the momentum not an increase in the mass. The momentum is in turn related to the velocity by:

$$ p = \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}} $$

where again $m$ is the (constant) rest mass.

However there is a situation in which absorption of a photon does lead to an increase in mass. Suppose we have a bound state like the electron in a hydrogen atom, and the photon is absorbed and excites the electron from the $1s$ to the $2s$ or some higher energy state. In this case the mass of the bound state increases by $E/c^2$, where $E$ is the photon energy. This is simply Einstein's famous equation $E=mc^2$ in action.

However in cases like this it is the mass of the whole bound state that increases, and not the mass of the electron or indeed any individual component of the bound state.

Comment: I agree with you totally. But I am curious about a question. If the electron has been excited by the photon, now we use a negative electric field around the atom to limit the movement of the electron, what will happen next?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you mean by putting a negative field around the atom. Can you explain the geometry of the field and how the field is generated? Maybe this should be a new question.

Comment: I use a cavity with electrons distributed on it. A metal is inside the cavity and we emit laser on the metal. Due to photo electrical effect, the electron in the metal will be accelerated. But the negative electrical field will limit the speed of the electrons. I predict that the photon in the electrons now will fly out of the electrons. Then it may fly out of the metal, or absorbed by the nucleus in metal. If the latter one happen, the nucleus will be accelerated which leads to the metal being accelerated. This may be a new way to invent a propulsion system even levitate the metal like an UFO

Answer (score 1):

Relativistic mass is a concept barely used. The idea behind it is that you can keep the classical formula,

$$ p = m_{rel}v  ,$$

where you define,

$$ m_{rel} = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}.$$

However this yields the correct formula,

$$ p = \frac{m_0v}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} ,$$

it causes interpretation issues, since in your example the relativistic mass would increase but this doesn't have a real physical interpretation, it is just a concept introduced to correct the classical formula $ p = mv$. Therefore this relativistic mass is not useful in most of the cases and is barely used nowadays.

Comment: As long as you are aware that "relativistic mass" is synonymous with "energy" according to Einstein's formula $E=m_{rel} c^2$ and that it is not the same as "rest mass" $m_0$,  there should be no problem in using this term, which you can (still) find in many basic textbooks.

Comment: Yeah indeed, I should have formulated it preciser. I didn't want to say that there is something dubious about the relativistic mass formulation of momentum, I wanted to note that for a beginner in relativity this formulation looks very analoguous with length contraction and that you could have been tempted to interpret this in the same way, i.e. a changing mass instead of a changing energy

Answer (score 0):

A situation where an electron could absorb a photon is when the electron is in an atom and the photon has the correct energy to allow the electron to move up to a higher quantized energy level. The modern view is that the rest mass of a fundamental particle, like the electron, is always the same. However, one can talk of the rest mass of a composite system, such as an atom, changing.

Before the absorption, choose a frame where the atom is stationary and say its mass is $m_i$ and the photons energy is $E_\gamma$. After the absorption call atom's mass  $m_f$ and it's momentum $p_f$. Then from conservation of energy and the relativistic energy momentum formula:
$$m_i+E_\gamma=\sqrt{m_f^2+p_f^2}$$
where we are setting the speed of light $c=1$. From conservation of momentum $p_f=E_\gamma$. Substituting this into the above equation and solving for $m_f$ gives
$$
m_f= \sqrt{m_i} \sqrt{2 E_{\gamma }+m_i}.
$$
In general, $E_\gamma\ll m_i$ and so we can expand the above expression to first order in $E_\gamma$ to get
$$
m_f\approx m_i+E_\gamma/c^2
$$
where we have restored the factors of $c$ using dimensional analysis.

Comment: This seems to be what the OP had in mind, but I'll point out to him or her that it is different than was written in the original question.  The electron does not absorb a photon, nor does its rest mass change.

Comment: @garyp I don't understand why you say the electron does not absorb a photon. If the electron is in an atom and the photon is of the right energy doesn't the electron absorb a photon and go to a higher energy level?

Comment: @Virgo because it is the total atom that absorbs the energy of the photon. It is just convenient to talk of an electron in an energy level  orbital around a nucleus, but in the rest frame of the electron it is the nucleus that has orbitals around the electron. One is in the special relativity regime, the invariant of the rest mass  is not a "modern view",  it is a basic tenet.

Comment: @annav OK, I think I see your point about the whole atom absorbing the photon. I called it the modern view as even the physicists like Feynman used to talk of the relatavistic mass where as now the correct approach is to just talk of the invariant rest mass.

Comment: This is not the first time I wish Feynman hadn't done that.